# How to resume dart generator?

Tags: dart, generator, yield

I want to use the same generator from different parts of code:

```
Stream<int> iter() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print('generated');
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() async {
  int counter = 0;
  final myIter = iter().asBroadcastStream();
  await for (var i in myIter) {
    print(i);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 3) break;
  }
  counter = 0;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  await for (var i in myIter) { // << not entering this cycle
    print(i);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 3) break;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work (the output is 0, 1, 2, 3) - the second generator is probably empty.

Is it possible to resume the generator (to get the second output of 4, 5, 6, 7)?

Comment: I think it'd probably be easier to wrap the `Stream` with a [`StreamQueue`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue-class.html) and operate on that.

Comment: The stream you listened to is a broadcast stream (wrapper). It never stopped sending events. While your code was awaiting the 1-second `Future.delayed`, it happily emitted events 4 through 99.
When the second `await for` came around, the stream was already done.
You can use the callbacks to `asBroadcastStream` to pause the underlying stream while the broadcast stream wrapper has no listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I used `StreamQueue` as suggested by @jamesdlin:

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';

Stream<int> iter() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print('generated');
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() async {
  final myIter = StreamQueue(iter());
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= 3; counter++) print(await myIter.next);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= 3; counter++) print(await myIter.next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a stream controller for something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Stream<int> iter() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() async {
  final controller = StreamController<int>.broadcast()..addStream(iter());

  int counter = 0;

  await for (var i in controller.stream) {
    print(i);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 3) break;
  }

  counter = 0;

  await for (var i in controller.stream) {
    print(i);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 3) break;
  }
}
```